# Restore Batchfile, VB script shortcut in new System XP

Tags: windows-xp, registry

In my old system (XP) I created many shortcuts in a folder on my desktop to open programs like eclipse, notepad++, etc. and some script files. I assigned shortcuts like 
<kbd>Cnrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for Eclipse, <kbd>Cnrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for notepad, etc.

I have backed up and restored the shortcuts folder on the desktop and batch/script file folder to my new system in the same path.

Is there any script to register all the shortcut to registry in one go?

Answer (score 0):

The hotkey is a function of the file.

XP looks in 4 places to discover hotkeys:

```
%UserProfile%\desktop
%AllUsersProfile%\desktop
%UserProfile%\Start Menu
%AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu
```

and in these three file types:

```
*.lnk
*.pif
*.url
```

as long as the files are in those locations, the hotkeys should still work

This vbs script will show you the hotkey assigned to a file:

```
on error resume next
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell" )
Set Arg=Wscript.Arguments
set lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(Arg)
If lnk.hotkey <> "" then
msgbox Arg & vbcrlf & lnk.hotkey
End If
```

use it with the filename passed to the script, e.g. `thescript.vbs %UserProfile%\desktop\myshortcut.lnk`